# Pitch Slider WP theme shows 123 under slider don't know why

Tags: wordpress, slider, pitch

I am using Pitch theme for Wordpress and everything is fine except one thing... Under my slider there is the numbers 123 but I don't know why... 
Look on: http://www.t-tlichtengeluid.nl/

I don't know where to find my problem and how I must delete this awful 123

Can somebody help me please? Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

123 are control navigations buttons. If you click on one of these digits the respective slide will be shown.

To hide them, open http://www.t-tlichtengeluid.nl/wp-content/themes/pitch/js/nivo/nivo-slider.css and change`.nivo-controlNav` (it's at the end of file) with:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
display: none !important;
}
```

Hope it helps!